# how to add number for every content in views?

Tags: views

i useing drupal 8.
i create ResTful export with views.
my site have several content type and i use several views for any content type.
but in clinet(android) i need have list with specified numbers...so i cant use Nid(Because i have several content type)
how i can add number for every content in my views?
(such as this pic that firefox add number(0)to my every content)
(upside down number this image)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Field in Views that counts the result rows. The Field is called `View result counter` and you can find it under `Global` Category.

Humans usually prefer to start count at 1, but there is an option in that Field settings to set the `Starting value` so you can use zero.

I haven't tried it with Rest export, grouping like in your screenshot won't work. It will just be one of the fields.

Comment: i think thats what I wanted! but i think drupal have bug for restful export with View result counter !
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPFBE.png

Comment: Yes it seems there is a bug. What version are you using? Will you report it if you don't find an existing one? https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=restful+services+views&status=All

Answer (score 0):

Mahdi Baghery,
You can customize the JSON response using views plugin that extends Serializer
like https://cgit.drupalcode.org/one_api/tree/src/Plugin/views/style/SerializerCount.php

The above SerializerCount.php code is used to add pager to ResTful export like http://one-drupal-demo.technikh.com/onedrupal/api/v1/content?page=1

```
{
results: [],
pager: {}
}
```

This JSON is parsed by Drupal 8 Android app at https://github.com/onedrupal/One-Drupal-Android. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technikh.onedrupal